# How to send a parameter in form_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, form-helpers

I want to send a parameter in form_tag helper like we can send a parameter through link_to helper in rails like this:

```
<%= link_to("Send Invitation", {:controller => 'l_home', :action => 'sendConnectRequest', foo: "hello world!!!"}, :class => "btn-primary")%>
```

Similarly I am trying to do this 
`<%= form_tag({:action => "sendConnectRequest", :method => 'post',  foo: "hello world!!!"}) do %>`in order to send a parameter in form_tag, but it is not working :(

Help needed

Thanks

Comment: What is it you're attempting to do, precisely? Do you mean that you want to have a piece of data within the form that gets sent to the server when the form is submitted?

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to send the data to the server and catch that data in controller. I donot want user to enter it, i just want to send it to controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there's a couple of ways to do this but the first that popped in my head. I think the easiest approach is to simply place the data you want in a hidden field inside the `form_tag`. Like so:

```
<%= form_tag ...your form_tag params... do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :foo, "hello world" %>
<%end%>
```

That will get sent to the server accessible by `params[:foo]`.

Here's some [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag) regarding the `hidden_field_tag`.

Hope that helps